# PDF loaded via embed tag blocked by frame-src directive in CSP

Tags: html, chromium, content-security-policy

I had made a minimum reproducible example in a sandbox but it turns out sandboxes block plugins so we'll just have to go by description of the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; child-src 'none'; object-src https://www.w3.org; connect-src *;"
    />
    <title>PDF CSP Violation Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed
      type="application/pdf"
      src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Given the above HTML, a PDF will be loaded in the PDF Viewer plugin in Firefox and Safari, but not in Google Chrome or in Microsoft Edge. Those last two browsers will complain it violates the `frame-src` directive which falls back on `child-src`. I've not been able to find anything explaining this violation, as by description `frame-src` is for `iframe` elements and `object-src` handles `embed` tags. I'm assuming the underlying problem has to do with Chromium and the way it displays PDFs, since both Chrome and Edge are built on top of Chromium.

My question is, is there an explanation as two why this is a violation of the directive, or is it possibly a bug in Chromium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari and Firefox acts exactly according to the CSP spec - the `<embed>` / `<object>` tags are covered by the `object-src` directive.

Chromium-based browsers ([since Chrome 76](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1002610)) behaves contradict to the CSP spec: they first check sources of the `<embed>` / `<object>` tags by the `object-src` directive and after that perform checking by the `frame-src` (or by the `child-src` or `default-src` on fallback).
This does not looks like Chrome bug because in case of [embedding png/jpg](https://csplite.com/csp/test395/#PNG) images a Chrome uses only `object-src` directive. But if you embed a "complex" object like svg/pdf/mp4 - Chrome performs second check via `frame-src`.

Most likely, Chrome "knows" something about the insecurity of using `<embed>` / `<object>` tags. The solution is not to use these tags, but to use `<iframe>` instead.

> 

**About unsafe and outdated of `<embed>` / `<object>` tags**

The `<embed>` / `<object>` tags based on plugin technologies - user have to install third-party plugins to render content which browser does not understand.
These tags do not support modern security mechanisms (such as the *allow=*, *csp=*, *sandbox=* attributes) therefore they are obsoleted in favour `<iframe>`, see [From object to iframe — other embedding technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies).

Most modern browsers [have deprecated and removed support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) for browser plug-ins, so relying upon `<embed>` is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser.

An `<object>` element mostly was used to embed Adobe Flash which is [insecure and outdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies#the_case_against_plugins).
*Due to its inherent issues and the lack of support for Flash, Adobe announced that they would stop supporting it at the end of 2020.  As of January 2020, most browsers block Flash content by default, and by December 31st of 2020, all browsers will have completely removed all Flash functionality. Any existing Flash content will be inaccessible after that date.*

To keep some backward compatibility, browsers implemented their own built-in plugins to render some kind of embedding contents. Thats why you can still embed PDF/VIDEO/AUDIO/SVG using `<embed>` / `<object>`.
But in some cases browsers forcely replace `<object>` by `<iframe>` - just create page with:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/9Ey_oeLlM9I&hl=en&fs=1&cc_load_policy=1"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/9Ey_oeLlM9I&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

and check real html code - the `<object>` and `<embed>` tags are replaced with `<iframe>` one. Some versions of Firefox rise a warning in the console like that:

```
Replace old Flash Player-based YouTube embeds by their new HTML5 counterparts.
Params were not supported by iframe embedds and were converted.
Please update the page code to use an iframe instead of embed/object, if possible.
```

Comment: "Most likely, Chrome "knows" something about the insecurity of using <embed> / <object> tags. The solution is not to use these tags, but to use <iframe> instead."  

Do you happen to have any sources that speak to <embed> / <object> tags having security issues that iframes do not have? Not that you were asserting it was a fact, just that otherwise it doesn't so much feel like a solution, but a workaround to Chromium based browsers not conforming to the spec.

Comment: The fact is that the behavior of Chrome depends on the type of embedded content. So it's not looks like a bug because this is provided in the browser code. About unsafe `<embed>` pls see updated answer.